# Switching from HereMap to lwuit form

Tags: java-me, here-api, lwuit-form

Am trying to display a lwuit form when the map is long clicked but I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at bw.a(), bci=1
at bw.<init>(), bci=6
at bt.<init>(), bci=10
at by.<init>(), bci=48
at bj.a(), bci=10
at fv.<init>(), bci=54
at ex.<init>(), bci=11
at ed.<init>(), bci=33
at com.org.whatsaround.WhatsAroundMidlet.showLocationView(), bci=17
at gm.commandAction(), bci=80
at b.a(), bci=59
at v.b(), bci=10
at c.d(), bci=6
at ez.gestureAction(), bci=237
at com.nokia.mid.ui.gestures.GestureHandler.handleGestureEvent(), bci=60
at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process(), bci=421
at com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run(), bci=182
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:661)
```

The code is

```
public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if (c == LONG_TOUCH) {

            GeoCoordinate coord = longTouch.getTouchAt();

            WhatsAroundMidlet.getInstance().showLocationView(country, phoneNumber, firstName, lastName, pTitle, pCategory, backListener, profilePic, coord);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be seen from your stack trace, the exception is thrown in your code in the method `showLocationView()`, the `NullPointerException` is probably due to one of the parameters in the method call (`country`, `phoneNumber`, `firstName`, `lastName`,etc.) passing in a object which has not been initialised.

If `coord` is at fault, you could check this as follows:

```
 if (c == LONG_TOUCH) {
      GeoCoordinate coord = longTouch.getTouchAt();
      System.out.println(coord);
 }
```

Otherwise you are on your own since you haven't explained how and where in your code  `country`, `phoneNumber`, `firstName`, `lastName`,etc. are actually populated.

Where the names of the functions in the stack trace are un-obfuscated, you can ascertain the following:

- `com.org.whatsaround.WhatsAroundMidlet.showLocationView()` - within this method the exception is thrown.
- `gm.commandAction()` - firing of the `Command` callback - i.e. entering your own code.
- `ez.gestureAction()` - processing of the gesture within the `maps-gesture.jar`
- `com.nokia.mid.ui.gestures.GestureHandler.handleGestureEvent()` - This is the Gesture handler created by the  `maps-gesture.jar` which has been invoked due to the long press.
- `com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process()` - this is passing events to all registered listeners, in your case this is a LONG PRESS event.
- `com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run()` - underlying event loop (from the emulator perhaps?)

Comment: You are right, the coord parameter was not initialized. Thanks big time